# Bluetooth send information to android phone

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to simply send a button press from a paired device to an android phone. Is this possible without using bluetooth 4.0?

Comment: Yes. Even if you pair two device using normal pairing process, then you can send any info as usual even without BLE 4.0. Can you expand what do you want to do?

Comment: Very basically i want to push a button on the paired device and have that activate a feature on an app.

Answer (score 0):

you can't literally "push a button" on another device, you can send some information, that when received on the other device will invoke the same method the button invokes.
for that u must implement a BT client-server pattern.
i suggest you read about it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html